# DISM fails. Worked once, but SFC was failing. Now DISM fails on restore

Tags: windows-8, chkdsk, dism, sfc

I have a really strange problem similar to this, but not the same.

I started with `sfc /SCANNOW` and got the error:

Windows Resource Protection found corrupt files but was unable to fix some of them. Details are included in the CBS.Log windir\Logs\CBS\CBS.log. For example C:\Windows\Logs\CBS\CBS.log. Note that logging is currently not supported in offline servicing scenarios.

I then ran the two dism commands as outlined in another post here:

`dism /online /cleanup-image /scanhealth`

`dism /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth`

I ran sfc again, and I still get the same error after running sfc.

Any ideas?

Extract of my CBS.log file below

```
2014-05-14 18:59:08, Info CSI 00000862 [SR] Verify complete 2014-05-14 18:59:08, Info CSI 00000863 [SR] Verifying 100 (0x0000000000000064) components 2014-05-14 18:59:08, Info CSI 00000864 [SR] Beginning Verify and Repair transaction 2014-05-14 18:59:10, Info CSI 00000865 [DIRSD OWNER WARNING] Directory [ml:520{260},l:106{53}]"\?\C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.0\WPF\en-US" is not owned but specifies SDDL in component Microsoft-Windows-WPFCoreComp.Resources, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_INTEL (0), Culture = [l:10{5}]"en-us", VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type neutral, TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral
2014-05-14 18:59:10, Info CSI 00000866 [DIRSD OWNER WARNING] Directory [ml:520{260},l:118{59}]"\??\C:\WINDOWS\Inf\Windows Workflow Foundation 3.0.0.0\0409" is not owned but specifies SDDL in component Microsoft-Windows-WWFCoreComp.Resources, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_INTEL (0), Culture = [l:10{5}]"en-us", VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type neutral, TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral

2014-05-14 18:59:10, Info CSI 00000867 [DIRSD OWNER WARNING] Directory [ml:520{260},l:134{67}]"\??\C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework" is not owned but specifies SDDL in component Microsoft-Windows-WWFCoreComp, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_INTEL (0), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type neutral, TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral

2014-05-14 18:59:10, Info CSI 00000868 [DIRSD OWNER WARNING] Directory [ml:520{260},l:118{59}]"\??\C:\WINDOWS\Inf\Windows Workflow Foundation 3.0.0.0\0000" is not owned but specifies SDDL in component Microsoft-Windows-WWFCoreComp, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_INTEL (0), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type neutral, TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral

2014-05-14 18:59:10, Info CSI 00000869 [DIRSD OWNER WARNING] Directory [ml:520{260},l:114{57}]"\??\C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft" is not owned but specifies SDDL in component Microsoft-Windows-WWFCoreComp, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_INTEL (0), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type neutral, TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral

2014-05-14 18:59:10, Info CSI 0000086a [DIRSD OWNER WARNING] Directory [ml:520{260},l:144{72}]"\??\C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.0" is not owned but specifies SDDL in component Microsoft-Windows-WWFCoreComp, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_INTEL (0), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type neutral, TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral

2014-05-14 18:59:10, Info CSI 0000086b [DIRSD OWNER WARNING] Directory [ml:520{260},l:94{47}]"\??\C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies" is not owned but specifies SDDL in component Microsoft-Windows-WWFCoreComp, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_INTEL (0), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type neutral, TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral

2014-05-14 18:59:12, Info CSI 0000086c [SR] Verify complete 2014-05-14 18:59:12, Info CSI 0000086d [SR] Verifying 100 (0x0000000000000064) components 2014-05-14 18:59:12, Info CSI 0000086e [SR] Beginning Verify and Repair transaction 2014-05-14 18:59:15, Info CSI 0000086f [DIRSD OWNER WARNING] Directory [ml:128{64},l:126{63}]"\??\C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\MsDtc\en" is not owned but specifies SDDL in component Microsoft.Dtc.PowerShell.Non_msil.Resources, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_INTEL (0), Culture = [l:10{5}]"en-US", VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type neutral, TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral

2014-05-14 18:59:15, Info CSI 00000870 [DIRSD OWNER WARNING] Directory [ml:134{67},l:132{66}]"\??\C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\MsDtc\en-US" is not owned but specifies SDDL in component Microsoft.Dtc.PowerShell.Scripts.Resources, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_INTEL (0), Culture = [l:10{5}]"en-US", VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type neutral, TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral

2014-05-14 18:59:16, Info CSI 00000871 Ignoring duplicate ownership for directory [l:72{36}]"\??\C:\WINDOWS\microsoft.net\authman" in component Microsoft.Interop.Security.AzRoles, Version = 6.3.9600.16384, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_INTEL (0), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type neutral, TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral

2014-05-14 18:59:17, Info CSI 00000872 [SR] Verify complete 2014-05-14 18:59:17, Info CSI 00000873 [SR] Verifying 100 (0x0000000000000064) components 2014-05-14 18:59:17, Info CSI 00000874 [SR] Beginning Verify and Repair transaction 2014-05-14 18:59:22, Info CSI 00000875 [SR] Verify complete 2014-05-14 18:59:22, Info CSI 00000876 [SR] Verifying 100 (0x0000000000000064) components 2014-05-14 18:59:22, Info CSI 00000877 [SR] Beginning Verify and Repair transaction 2014-05-14 18:59:24, Info CSI 00000878 [DIRSD OWNER WARNING] Directory [ml:520{260},l:120{60}]"\??\C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\RedistList" is not owned but specifies SDDL in component NetFx-ASSEMBLYLIST_XML, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_INTEL (0), Culture neutral, VersionScope neutral, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:b03f5f7f11d50a3a}, Type neutral, TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral

2014-05-14 18:59:26, Info CSI 00000879 [SR] Verify complete 2014-05-14 18:59:26, Info CSI 0000087a [SR] Verifying 100 (0x0000000000000064) components 2014-05-14 18:59:26, Info CSI 0000087b [SR] Beginning Verify and Repair transaction 2014-05-14 18:59:30, Info CSI 0000087c [SR] Verify complete 2014-05-14 18:59:30, Info CSI 0000087d [SR] Verifying 100 (0x0000000000000064) components 2014-05-14 18:59:31, Info CSI 0000087e [SR] Beginning Verify and Repair transaction 2014-05-14 18:59:35, Info CSI 0000087f [SR] Verify complete 2014-05-14 18:59:35, Info CSI 00000880 [SR] Verifying 100 (0x0000000000000064) components 2014-05-14 18:59:35, Info CSI 00000881 [SR] Beginning Verify and Repair transaction 2014-05-14 18:59:39, Info CSI 00000882 [SR] Verify complete 2014-05-14 18:59:39, Info CSI 00000883 [SR] Verifying 100 (0x0000000000000064) components 2014-05-14 18:59:39, Info CSI 00000884 [SR] Beginning Verify and Repair transaction 2014-05-14 18:59:44, Info CSI 00000885 [SR] Verify complete 2014-05-14 18:59:44, Info CSI 00000886 [SR] Verifying 92 (0x000000000000005c) components 2014-05-14 18:59:44, Info CSI 00000887 [SR] Beginning Verify and Repair transaction 2014-05-14 18:59:46, Info CSI 00000888 [DIRSD OWNER WARNING] Directory [ml:520{260},l:56{28}]"\??\C:\WINDOWS\system\Speech" is not owned but specifies SDDL in component Windows-Media-SpeechSynthesis-WinRT, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_INTEL (0), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type neutral, TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral

2014-05-14 18:59:46, Info CSI 00000889 Ignoring duplicate ownership for directory [l:56{28}]"\??\C:\WINDOWS\system\Speech" in component Windows-Media-SpeechSynthesis-WinRT, Version = 6.3.9600.16384, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_INTEL (0), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type neutral, TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral

2014-05-14 18:59:48, Info CSI 0000088a [SR] Verify complete 2014-05-14 18:59:48, Info CSI 0000088b [SR] Repairing 1 components 2014-05-14 18:59:48, Info CSI 0000088c [SR] Beginning Verify and Repair transaction 2014-05-14 18:59:48, Info CSI 0000088d Hashes for file member \SystemRoot\WinSxS\amd64_windows-defender-am-sigs_31bf3856ad364e35_6.3.9600.16384_none_ad431e16ef9845da\MpAvBase.vdm do not match actual file [l:24{12}]"MpAvBase.vdm" : Found: {l:32 b:jSt1ClQt8/lLy9usSIKExS9+IbfzubLiw1rX8soXDmQ=} Expected: {l:32 b:0dMEhN7kYwcdydEE2kpJrc1jlT3hufXi/Vw24qdFm88=} 2014-05-14 18:59:48, Info CSI 0000088e [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:24{12}]"MpAvBase.vdm" of Windows-Defender-AM-Sigs, Version = 6.3.9600.16384, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64 (9), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type neutral, TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, hash mismatch 2014-05-14 18:59:49, Info CSI 0000088f Hashes for file member \SystemRoot\WinSxS\amd64_windows-defender-am-sigs_31bf3856ad364e35_6.3.9600.16384_none_ad431e16ef9845da\MpAvBase.vdm do not match actual file [l:24{12}]"MpAvBase.vdm" : Found: {l:32 b:jSt1ClQt8/lLy9usSIKExS9+IbfzubLiw1rX8soXDmQ=} Expected: {l:32 b:0dMEhN7kYwcdydEE2kpJrc1jlT3hufXi/Vw24qdFm88=} 2014-05-14 18:59:49, Info CSI 00000890 [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:24{12}]"MpAvBase.vdm" of Windows-Defender-AM-Sigs, Version = 6.3.9600.16384, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64 (9), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type neutral, TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, hash mismatch 2014-05-14 18:59:49, Info CSI 00000891 [SR] This component was referenced by [l:268{134}]"Windows-Defender-AM-Default-Definitions-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.3.9600.16384.Windows-Defender-AM-Default-Definitions-Package" 2014-05-14 18:59:49, Info CSI 00000892 Hashes for file member \??\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows Defender\Definition Updates\Default\MpAvBase.vdm do not match actual file [l:24{12}]"MpAvBase.vdm" : Found: {l:32 b:jSt1ClQt8/lLy9usSIKExS9+IbfzubLiw1rX8soXDmQ=} Expected: {l:32 b:0dMEhN7kYwcdydEE2kpJrc1jlT3hufXi/Vw24qdFm88=} 2014-05-14 18:59:50, Info CSI 00000893 Hashes for file member \SystemRoot\WinSxS\amd64_windows-defender-am-sigs_31bf3856ad364e35_6.3.9600.16384_none_ad431e16ef9845da\MpAvBase.vdm do not match actual file [l:24{12}]"MpAvBase.vdm" : Found: {l:32 b:jSt1ClQt8/lLy9usSIKExS9+IbfzubLiw1rX8soXDmQ=} Expected: {l:32 b:0dMEhN7kYwcdydEE2kpJrc1jlT3hufXi/Vw24qdFm88=} 2014-05-14 18:59:50, Info CSI 00000894 [SR] Could not reproject corrupted file [ml:520{260},l:144{72}]"\??\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows Defender\Definition Updates\Default"[l:24{12}]"MpAvBase.vdm"; source file in store is also corrupted 2014-05-14 18:59:50, Info CSI 00000895 [SR] Repair complete 2014-05-14 18:59:50, Info CSI 00000896 [SR] Committing transaction 2014-05-14 18:59:50, Info CSI 00000897 Creating NT transaction (seq 3), objectname [6]"(null)" 2014-05-14 18:59:50, Info CSI 00000898 Created NT transaction (seq 3) result 0x00000000, handle @0x60c 2014-05-14 18:59:50, Info CSI 00000899@2014/5/14:22:59:50.486 Beginning NT transaction commit... 2014-05-14 18:59:50, Info CSI 0000089a@2014/5/14:22:59:50.494 CSI perf trace: CSIPERF:TXCOMMIT;7897 2014-05-14 18:59:50, Info CSI 0000089b [SR] Verify and Repair Transaction completed. All files and registry keys listed in this transaction have been successfully repaired 2014-05-14 19:01:51, Info CBS Trusted Installer is shutting down because: SHUTDOWN_REASON_AUTOSTOP 2014-05-14 19:01:51, Info CBS TiWorker signaled for shutdown, going to exit. 2014-05-14 19:01:51, Info CBS Ending the TiWorker main loop. 2014-05-14 19:01:51, Info CBS Starting TiWorker finalization. 2014-05-14 19:01:51, Info CBS Ending the TrustedInstaller main loop. 2014-05-14 19:01:51, Info CBS Starting TrustedInstaller finalization. 2014-05-14 19:01:51, Info CBS Ending TrustedInstaller finalization. 2014-05-14 19:01:51, Info CBS Ending TiWorker finalization.
```

---

An update to this, I have now booted my Win 8.1 PC into safe mode, and run the commands so far as follows in sequence:

```
C:\Users\xxx>sfc /scannow

Beginning system scan.  This process will take some time.

Beginning verification phase of system scan.
Verification 84% complete.

Windows Resource Protection could not perform the requested operation.

C:\Users\xxx>dism /online /cleanup-image /scanhealth

Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool
Version: 6.3.9600.17031

Image Version: 6.3.9600.17031

[==========================100.0%==========================]
The component store is repairable.
The operation completed successfully.
```

---

Just started `C:\Users\xxx>dism /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth`, let's see where that takes me.

---

Safe mode the entire operation fails, gone back to the normal login and trying again

Just running the dism commands first.

One change I have made is I have shut down both Windows Defender and Bitdefender (which is what I usually use), just to make sure nothing is interfering with this operation.

```
    C:\Windows\system32>dism /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth

Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool
Version: 6.3.9600.17031

Image Version: 6.3.9600.17031

[==========================100.0%==========================]
The restore operation failed. Either the repair source was not found or the comp
onent store cannot be repaired.

Error: 0x800f081f

DISM failed. No operation was performed.
For more information, review the log file.

T

he DISM log file can be found at C:\Windows\Logs\DISM\dism.log attached below
    [1736] Caller did not request sparse mount
    [1736] Mounting new image.
    Wim:         [\\?\GLOBALROOT\device\harddisk0\partition1\Recovery\WindowsRE\Winre.wim]
    Image Index: [1]
    Mount Path:  [C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\1c1dac79-d424-4e72-97dd-9d1a38009824]
    [1736] Wimserv process started for guid b431bfc6-2ccb-4167-8df8-670082274df0.  Id is 1572
    [1572] ImageUnmarshallHandle: Reconstituting wim at \\?\GLOBALROOT\device\harddisk0\partition1\Recovery\WindowsRE\Winre.wim.
    [1572] Mounted image at C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\1c1dac79-d424-4e72-97dd-9d1a38009824.
    [1736] [0x8007007b] FIOReadFileIntoBuffer:(1415): The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
    [1736] [0xc142011c] UnmarshallImageHandleFromDirectory:(511)
    [1736] [0xc142011c] WIMGetMountedImageHandle:(2568)
    [1736] [0x8007007b] FIOReadFileIntoBuffer:(1415): The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
    [1736] [0xc142011c] UnmarshallImageHandleFromDirectory:(511)
    [1736] [0xc142011c] WIMGetMountedImageHandle:(2568)
    [1736] ImageUnmarshallHandle: Reconstituting wim at \\?\GLOBALROOT\device\harddisk0\partition1\Recovery\WindowsRE\Winre.wim.
    [1736] ImageUnmarshallHandle: Reconstituting wim at \\?\GLOBALROOT\device\harddisk0\partition1\Recovery\WindowsRE\Winre.wim.
    [1736] ImageUnmarshallHandle: Reconstituting wim at \\?\GLOBALROOT\device\harddisk0\partition1\Recovery\WindowsRE\Winre.wim.
    [1736] [0x80070070] ReadWriteDataInternal:(134): There is not enough space on the disk.
    [1736] [0x80070070] WriteDataCallback:(1143): There is not enough space on the disk.
    [1736] [0x80070070] AddCaptureNodeToImage:(4190): There is not enough space on the disk.
    [1736] [0xc144012e] 
    〲㌱ㄭⴰ㜱ㄠ㨶㌵㌺ⰵ䔠牲牯††††††††䐠卉⁍†䥄䵓圠䵉倠潲楶敤㩲倠䑉ㄽ㌷‶㩃坜湩潤獷呜浥屰挱搱捡㤷搭㈴ⴴ攴㈷㤭搷ⵤ搹愱㠳〰㠹㐲停潲牧浡䘠汩獥卜湹灡楴獣卜湹偔卜湹敓獮瑩癩瑩乹⹂海⁶䠨䕒啓呌〽㡸〰〷㜰⤰ⴠ䌠楗䵭湡条牥㨺楗偭潲楶敤䵲杳潌䍧污扬捡൫㈊㄰ⴳ〱ㄭ‷㘱㔺㨳㔳‬牅潲⁲††††††††䥄䵓†䐠卉⁍䥗⁍牐癯摩牥›䥐㵄㜱㘳䌠尺楗摮睯屳敔灭ㅜㅣ慤㝣ⴹ㑤㐲㐭㝥ⴲ㜹摤㤭ㅤ㍡〸㤰㈸尴牐杯慲⁭楆敬屳祓慮瑰捩屳祓呮屐祓卮湥楳楴楶祴䉎眮癭⠠剈卅䱕㵔砰〸㜰〰〷         ‭坃浩慍慮敧㩲场浩牐癯摩牥獍䱧杯慃汬慢正਍[1736] [0x80070070] ProcessWimQueueNode:(448): There is not enough space on the disk.
    [1736] [0x80070070] DequeueWimData:(303): There is not enough space on the disk.
    [1736] [0x80070070] ImageWorkerThread:(550): There is not enough space on the disk.
    [1736] [0x80070070] GetImageErrorCode:(3701): There is not enough space on the disk.
    [1736] [0x80070070] ResAddFromFileAndHandle:(4414): There is not enough space on the disk.
    [1736] [0xc144012e]
```

and a whole bunch of gibberish characters below that in the log file?

Comment: Is this related to [DSIM fails on my computer, Windows 8.1](http://superuser.com/q/753627/2357)?

Answer (score 0):

After you ran your last DISM prompt, In the cbs.log file it appears that you don't have sufficient write space on your disk, If this is the case you must free up some room on your hard drive. You should never fill a hdd completely as you need to leave breathing space for the operating system to perform rewrites. You shouldn't fill a hdd past %80- %85.