# DISM /StartComponentCleanup fails, but /ScanHealth reports healthy

Tags: windows-8, command-line, windows-8.1, dism

My WinSxS cleanup task was giving the "Last Run Result" of `The component store has been corrupted. (0x80073712)`. No problem, to elevated command prompt and DISM.

```
>DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /ScanHealth

Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool
Version: 6.3.9600.17031

Image Version: 6.3.9600.17031

[==========================100.0%==========================]
No component store corruption detected.
The operation completed successfully.
```

OK Great, should be ready to clean.

```
>DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /StartComponentCleanup

Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool
Version: 6.3.9600.17031

Image Version: 6.3.9600.17031

[==========================100.0%==========================]

Error: 14098

The component store has been corrupted.

The DISM log file can be found at C:\WINDOWS\Logs\DISM\dism.log
```

Odd, let's fix that up.

```
>DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth

Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool
Version: 6.3.9600.17031

Image Version: 6.3.9600.17031

[==========================100.0%==========================]
The restore operation completed successfully. The component store corruption was repaired.
The operation completed successfully.
```

Let's be safe and re-scan.

```
>DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /ScanHealth

Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool
Version: 6.3.9600.17031

Image Version: 6.3.9600.17031

[==========================100.0%==========================]
No component store corruption detected.
The operation completed successfully.
```

And on to cleanup

```
>DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /StartComponentCleanup

Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool
Version: 6.3.9600.17031

Image Version: 6.3.9600.17031

[==========================100.0%==========================]

Error: 14098

The component store has been corrupted.

The DISM log file can be found at C:\WINDOWS\Logs\DISM\dism.log
```

I'm totally at a loss. How can it report as non-corrupted, repaired and corrupted all in quick succession?

Anyone considering relation [of this question](https://superuser.com/questions/753608/dsim-fails-worked-once-but-sfc-was-failing-now-dsim-fails-on-restore), `sfc` is of no use either.

```
>sfc /scannow

Beginning system scan.  This process will take some time.

Beginning verification phase of system scan.
Verification 100% complete.

Windows Resource Protection did not find any integrity violations.
```

**TL;DR: My SxS store is non-corrupt, repaired and corrupted. At the same time. Unsure how to fix.**

Comment: Any further clues in the log files as to what is going on? C:\Windows\Logs\CBS\CBS.log & C:\Windows\Logs\DISM\dism.log... Have you tried to repair using the Powershell command Repair-WindowsImage (not sure of the switches off the top of my head sorry..)

Comment: upload the CBS and DISM log files, I'll take a look at them later.

Comment: As totally non-helpful as it is, I decided I should have posted the outcome. I rebooted and it worked fine. Pride a little damaged I didn't try that before posting, but there you go. Sorry all for the delay!

Comment: You should post your own answer and accept that as the answer so it's clear in case others ever find this helpful and that there is a clear answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original poster fixed the problem by rebooting - `dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth` is indeed the command that needs to be run for Windows 8 and newer.

---

There is another tool that can be helpful in this kind of situation: CheckSUR, also known as the System Update Readiness Tool. You can download it **for Windows 7 and before** from [KB947821](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/947821).

According to [this Microsoft blog post](http://blogs.technet.com/b/joscon/archive/2010/05/26/using-checksur-and-update-packages-to-fix-corruption.aspx), CheckSUR can usually fix corruption in the component store, but when it can't, it's still possible to use it to identify the affected components. Near the end of the CheckSUR log is a list of packages; these entries correspond to Windows updates and KB articles. Get the MSU from `https://support.microsoft.com/kb/NUMBER-HERE` and place it in the `\Windows\CheckSur\packages` folder, which you may have to create. Re-run CheckSUR after you've done that for each package.

Note that CheckSUR [may take a while to do its thing](http://blogs.technet.com/b/joscon/archive/2010/05/11/why-does-checksur-take-a-long-time-to-run.aspx).

Comment: While I wasn't able to test this out it sounds like a good solution so I'll mark accepted

Answer (score 0):

Had same issue.  Mine was caused by an Antivirus Conflict

It was ESET File Security for Microsoft Windows Server v.6.3.12010.0

Added an exclusion for C:\Windows\WinSxS

Also added an exclusion for process dism.exe

---

Comment: Issue came back again.  At a loss.

Comment: Add the exclusions again and see if that resolves like you said it did the first time