# Windows Update causing server meltdown

Tags: windows-update, windows-server-2012-r2, dism

A failed windows update caused my Windows Server 2012 R2 install to have a meltdown.

Update package:

> Microsoft-Windows-NetFx4-OC-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.3.9600.16384

failed and every time the computer reboots it says "Installing Updates 35%" then reboots and says it was unable to install updates and attempts to undo changes.  I also no longer have access to roles and features and am getting the error:
"Online - Cannot get role and feature data".

If I try running

> "sfc /scannow"

it says "There is a system repair pending which requires reboot to complete". and rebooting Windows obviously doesn't help.

I also tried running:

> dism /online /remove-package /packagename:Microsoft-Windows-NetFx4-OC-
>   Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.3.9600.16384"

Which fails with:

> Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool
>   Version: 6.3.9600.17031
>
> Image Version: 6.3.9600.17031
>
> Processing 1 of 1 - An error occurred - Microsoft-Windows-NetFx4-OC-Package >Error: 0x80070005
>
> Error: 5
>
> Access is denied.
>
> The DISM log file can be found at C:\Windows\Logs\DISM\dism.log

Any help would be much appreciated.

I basically am having the issue reported here: [link](https://superuser.com/questions/773630/dism-startcomponentcleanup-fails-but-scanhealth-reports-healthy)

Comment: upload the folder C:\Windows\logs\ as zip to a cloud service like Dropbox/OneDrive and post a link here.

Comment: have you uploaded the logs?

Comment: I ended up just spinning up another server, this was acting as a file server so obviously it needed to be back up and running quickly.  I believe what happened was there was a power outage during a feature installation.