# Failed Update causing Server to stop working properly Windows Server 2012 R2

Tags: windows-server-2012

Basically, the exact same issue as the question posted here:

[Windows Update causing server meltdown](https://superuser.com/questions/925484/windows-update-causing-server-meltdown?newreg=2380b7044a854c399d25bf9dc1b43c86)

Unfortunately the server is the only physical server in the office so simply using another server as the user in that post did isn't an option here. I've uploaded the logs here:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/1pvcd4kxe22nob3/Logs.zip?dl=0

Any help would be apreciated! SFC /Scannow asks for reboot, of course tried rebooting but no luck
Server Manager also asks to reboot but rebooting makes no difference again
DISM /restorehealth resulted in a error also